# TypeError: Network request failed. Android

Tags: react-native

Fetch with http:// request is giving error and with https:// its working fine

eg

```
getData(){
  fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
})
.then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
       console.log('responseJson >>>>'+JSON.stringify(responseJson));

    })
   .catch((error) => {
      console.error('error>>>>>'+error);
    });
```

}

React Version
 "react": "16.6.3",
 "react-native": "0.58.5"

** Device has network connection as in the device browser web pages are loading.

Comment: working fine for me.

Comment: Did this worked in android ?

Comment: Yes bro I checked in Android, iOS and web browser... It's working completely fine... Might you facing some internal issue.

Comment: Android 9 (API level 28 - RN 59 builds with 28), cleartext traffic support is disabled by default.

Solution:

Removed ./android/app/src/debug folder
add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to ./adnroid/app/src/main/AndroidManifest:
     <application
       ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
     ...>